# Ball no longer moves in BallWallBounce (Art and Science of Java Ex4.15)

Tags: java

From the Art and Science of Java Chapter 4, Exercise 15. I am suppose to write a program that animates a ball bouncing within the window from edge to edge.

Here is my code:

```
import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.program.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class BouncingBall extends GraphicsProgram {

private static final int N_STEPS=1000;
private static final int PAUSE_TIME = 2;
private static final double ovalsize =50;

public void run(){
    GOval oval = new GOval(getWidth()/2-ovalsize/2,getHeight()/2-ovalsize/2, ovalsize, ovalsize);
    //positions the ball's start position at the center of the window
    oval.setFilled(true);
    add (oval);
    double dx=((getWidth()-ovalsize)/4)/N_STEPS;
    double dy=((getHeight()-ovalsize)/2)/N_STEPS;
    while(true) {
        oval.move(dx, dy);   //indicates the oval moving
        pause(PAUSE_TIME);
        if (oval.getY() > getHeight() - ovalsize) {//code indicates if ball encounters any edge
                                                    //of the screen, it will change direction.
            dy*=-1; 
        }
        if(oval.getX() > getWidth()- ovalsize) {
            dx*=-1;
        }
        if(oval.getY() < 0) {
            dy*=dy-1;
        }
        if(oval.getX() < 0) {
            dx*=-1;
        }
    }   
}
```

}

I used the code from http://tenasclu.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/first-few-days-of-learning-to-program.html to help me understand how the ball needs to bounce from one edge of the window back.

After making the program run, I realize that when I change:

```
double dx=((getWidth()-ovalsize)/4)/N_STEPS;
double dy=((getHeight()-ovalsize)/2)/N_STEPS;
```

to

```
double dx = (getWidth()/N_STEPS);
double dy = (getWidth()/N_STEPS);
```

(which is the code from the other webpage), the ball no longer moves.

Can anyone tell me what's happening?

EDIT: I went back to test the program and it appears there is another problem with the code that might be related to this. When I start the application, the ball will move as normal. Then it will move faster and faster and after about 62 seconds, the ball will bug out and move back and forth only at the top edge of the window.